# Vercel server side live link not loading the the data. On the other hand I am getting all the data from database locally

Tags: vercel

https://garibazar-server.vercel.app/allProducts

Here is my server site live link. I have tried everything, googled a lot but still couldn't figure out what to do.. I am getting all the data locally but after deploy data is not showing. I have also added environment variables..

Can anyone help me figuring this problem?

https://i.ibb.co/Yh5khDT/1.png (locally data is loading)

https://i.ibb.co/f9LDdkJ/2.png (vercel link is not working)

https://i.ibb.co/wYh4Q92/3.png